# Load KML doesn't always show icons in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: kml, openlayers

I've been able to successfully load a KML file and overlay the data on a map. However if I move the files to a new server (and update all references to the new server) none of my kml file data gets displayed. I've got it to work in one location but when I move it no kml data. I've checked references to images, and file location.

I'm also using Layerswitcher https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher

After checking and double checking references, I still got nothing.

```
My layerswitcher script:

var mapMinZoom = 6;
var mapMaxZoom = 21;

var mapBounds = [ -76.644773, 42.424805, -76.357081, 42.631565 ];
var centerLat = (mapBounds[1] + mapBounds[3]) / 2;
var centerLng = (mapBounds[0] + mapBounds[2]) / 2;

var xml_data = 'http://www.myserver.com/data/assets/rep_short.kml';
(function() {

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target : 'map',
        layers : [ new ol.layer.Group({
            'title' : 'Base maps',
            layers : [ new ol.layer.Tile({
                title : 'Base Map',
                type : 'base',
                visible : true,
                source : new ol.source.OSM()
            }) ]
        }), new ol.layer.Group({
            title : 'Overlays',
            layers : [ new ol.layer.Vector({
                title : 'Properties',
                source : new ol.source.KML({
                    projection : 'EPSG:3857',
                    url : xml_data
                })
            }) ]
        }) ],
        view : new ol.View({
            projection : 'EPSG:3857',
            center : ol.proj.transform([ centerLng, centerLat ], 'EPSG:4326',
                    'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom : 12
        })
    });

    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel : 'Légende' // Optional label for button
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);

    var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
    //map.addOverlay(popup);

    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        var prettyCoord = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(
                evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'), 2);
        popup.show(evt.coordinate, '<div><h2>Coordinates</h2><p>' + prettyCoord
                + '</p></div>');
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a content management system that generates a system url

Since my reference to the kml file was different than:
var xml_data = 'http://www.myserver.com/data/assets/rep_short.kml';

Openlayers seemed to have a problem with the different urls as a cross domain conflict? Not sure.

If I reference the kml in Openlayers with a url like:
http://www.myserver.com/data/index.php/mycontroller/xml_data

Openlayers plots the kml data.

Comment: Probably a CORS issue, the problem is not Openlayers. Verify that the request has the correct CORS headers.